# Trouble with Mock.Assert() for sequential calls with different argument values to mock

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, telerik, justmock

Could someone please take a look at the demo code below and let me know if what I'm seeing is due to error on my part or a Telerik issue?

I'm using Telerik.JustMock v. 2014.1.1519.1. and Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework v. 10.0.0.0.

As the code comments note, I get the expected results when the id variables are equal (one call for each of the ids), but not when they're different. When I step through the first test I can see the expected calls being made, but JustMock then tells me they weren't made.

I'll appreciate any constructive thoughts. Hopefully this isn't a case of me not getting enough sleep...

```
[TestClass]
public class RunnerTests
{
[TestMethod]
public void MakeTwoCallsDifferentIdsFails()
{
    int idOne=1;
    int idTwo=2;

    DataTable dt=new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Id");
    dt.Rows.Add(idOne);
    dt.Rows.Add(idTwo);

    IProcessor mock = Mock.Create<IProcessor>();
    Runner runner = new Runner(mock);
    runner.Process(dt);

    Mock.Assert(()=>mock.Process(Arg.IsAny<MyArgs>()), Occurs.Exactly(2));
    //The following two asserts fail (with 0 calls made to mock), regardless of sequence:
    Mock.Assert(()=>mock.Process(Arg.Matches<MyArgs>     
       (d=>d.Id==idOne)),Occurs.Once());
    Mock.Assert(()=>mock.Process(Arg.Matches<MyArgs>
       (d=>d.Id==idTwo)),Occurs.Once());
}

[TestMethod]
public void MakeTwoCallsSameIdPasses()
{
    //ids intentionally equal:
    int idOne=1;
    int idTwo=1;

    DataTable dt=new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Id");
    dt.Rows.Add(idOne);
    dt.Rows.Add(idTwo);

    IProcessor mock = Mock.Create<IProcessor>();
    Runner runner = new Runner(mock);
    runner.Process(dt);

    //all asserts pass:
    Mock.Assert(()=>mock.Process(Arg.IsAny<MyArgs>()), Occurs.Exactly(2));
    //The following two pass:
    Mock.Assert(()=>mock.Process(Arg.Matches<MyArgs>     
        (d=>d.Id==idOne)),Occurs.Exactly(2));
    Mock.Assert(()=>mock.Process(Arg.Matches<MyArgs>
        (d=>d.Id==idTwo)),Occurs.Exactly(2));
}
}

public interface IProcessor
{
    void Process(MyArgs args);
}

public class MyArgs
{
    public void UpdateId(int newId)
    {
        this.Id = newId;
    }

    public int Id {get; private set;}
}

public class Runner
{
    private IProcessor processor;

    public Runner(IProcessor processor)
    {
        this.processor=processor;
    }

    public void Process(DataTable dt)
    {
        MyArgs args = new MyArgs();

        foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(row["Id"]);
            args.UpdateId(id);
            processor.Process(args);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: In the test method that fails, if I completely remove one of the int variables and explicitly assert that the *other* was called exactly once, the test passes. Things seem to go south only when I throw that second, different value into the mix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't get our mocking framework of choice (JustMock) to accomplish what I wanted, I ended up applying [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), forgot about the mocking framework for this test, and went with something like the following:

I changed my test method to look like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TwoCallsDifferentIds()
    {
        int idOne = 1;
        int idTwo = 2;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id");
        dt.Rows.Add(idOne);
        dt.Rows.Add(idTwo);
        FakeProcessor processor = new FakeProcessor();
        Runner runner = new Runner(processor);
        runner.Process(dt);

        Assert.AreEqual(2, processor.MyArgsIds.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, processor.MyArgsIds[0]);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, processor.MyArgsIds[1]);
    }
```

and added the following fake:

```
public class FakeProcessor : IProcessor
{
    private IList<int> mList = new List<int>();

    public IList<int> MyArgsIds 
    {
        get { return mList; }
    }

    public void Process(MyArgs args)
    {
        mList.Add(args.Id);
    }
}
```

Not as slick, perhaps, but it got me the test I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The mock records that it was called twice with the same instance of `MyArgs`. The fact that the instance contents are different between the two calls is lost to it, though. When you get to the point where you assert the calls, the recorded `MyArgs` argument has an `Id` equal to 2 in the failing test.

If you change your `Process` method to

```
public void Process(DataTable dt)
{
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        MyArgs args = new MyArgs();
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(row["Id"]);
        args.UpdateId(id);
        processor.Process(args);
    }
}
```

both tests will pass.

**EDIT:**

You can get the desired behavior using JustMock by stating your expectations in arrangements, like so:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MakeTwoCallsDifferentIdsFails()
{
    int idOne = 1;
    int idTwo = 2;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Id");
    dt.Rows.Add(idOne);
    dt.Rows.Add(idTwo);

    IProcessor mock = Mock.Create<IProcessor>();
    Mock.Arrange(() => mock.Process(Arg.Matches<MyArgs>(d => d.Id == idOne))).OccursOnce();
    Mock.Arrange(() => mock.Process(Arg.Matches<MyArgs>(d => d.Id == idTwo))).OccursOnce();

    Runner runner = new Runner(mock);
    runner.Process(dt);

    Mock.Assert(mock);
}
```

The reason why this works is that the occurrence expectations are marked as met as soon as the right calls happen, so the predicate to `Arg.Matches` works with the live values of the arguments passed to the method, not post fact when the saved argument instances may have mutated.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I agree with everything in your response, I'd just have expected my code to work, given the Matches<> method name and signature. You think this is by design, and JustMock doesn't have the capability to do what I'm asking it to do? If I modify my original code to use Moq, whose syntax is similar, the test passes. (Just a bit of validation for me, that I'm not asking my mocking framework to do something extraordinary.)

Comment: I just ran the failing test just like you posted it with Moq 4.2. I see exactly the same behavior as with JustMock.

Comment: handle.Verify(m => m.Process(It.Is<MyArgs>
      (d => d.Id == idOne)), Times.Once()); //fails: 0
   handle.Verify(m => m.Process(It.Is<MyArgs>
      (d => d.Id == idTwo)), Times.Once()); //fails: 2

Comment: You're right. My bad--trying to do too many things at once. I see the same thing with Moq.